# Unable to center the text in TextView when width is set to 'match_parent'

Tags: android, layout, textview, text-align

I am relatively new to the Android SDK and am working with a TextView amongst other components on my activity UI. When I set the width to `wrap_content` and use `layout_gravity`, I am able to center the TextView in my parent container. However, I now need to give the TextView a background that stretches fully along the width of the parent and so I set the width to `match_parent`. Once I do this, neither `layout_gravity` nor `textAlignment="center"` are able to center the text within the view. This is the code I am using:

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/trackName"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textSize="28sp"
        android:paddingTop="7dp"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:background="#99000000" />
```

This is what the activity UI looks like right now:

[image]

How can I fix this and align my text to the center of the TextView control? Please help!

Comment: try using `android:gravity:` instead of `android:layout_gravity:`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use `android:gravity`. As the docs say:

> [gravity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#gravity) Specifies how an object should position its content, on both the X and Y axes, within its own bounds.
>
> [layout_gravity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#layout_gravity) Standard gravity constant that a child supplies to its parent. Defines how the child view should be positioned, on both the X and Y axes, within its enclosing layout.

Answer (score 3):

Use `gravity` instead of `layout_gravity`

### Difference between them

`android:gravity` sets the gravity of the content of the View its used on and `android:layout_gravity` sets the gravity of the View or Layout in its parent.

Try this that should solve your problem.

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="@string/trackName"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="28sp"
    android:paddingTop="7dp"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:background="#99000000" />
```

Answer (score 1):

```
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
```

Difference between gravity and layout_gravity :

layout_gravity means the gravity of the widet in its layout. you have used width as match_parent. So your textview is already occupying all the space.

gravity means the gravity of the content of that view. i.e. gravity of the text in your textview. u have to place that text in the center, not the textview.